# Upgrade CPU from Athlon 64 X2 4200+

Tags: amd-athlon

I have a Gaming PC with the following specs:

- Mainboard: M2N-SLI Deluxe
- CPU: AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4200+

I want to buy a new CPU, but I am unsure, what is up and down in AMD's CPU series. The mainboard supports the following sockets:

- AMD® Socket AM2+
- AM2 Phenom FX (2000MT/s), Phenom (2000MT/s)
- Athlon 64 X2
- Athlon 64 FX, Sempron

So which of the above sockets are "better" than the 64 X2?

Comment: Go to a website like http://www.newegg.com and filter the CPU by AMD, then by Socket AM2+, that will get you your choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to go to the website of the motherboard, download the newest manual and see the list of supported CPUs (the list may be a separate file in the downloads section).

This way, you'll be sure that the CPU will actually work. Pay special attention to any required BIOS updates! I know of people who got a new CPU, sold the old one and then found out that a BIOS update is needed for the new CPU to work.

One you have list of CPUs that will work, go to [AMD's desktop CPU site](http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUResult.aspx) and compare the CPUs on the supported list.